PXE Boot performing randomly from cascaded switches
I'm facing PXE-boot issues within a school network. I'm posting here to make sure I'm not missing something on switches configurations. The issue is that PXE-boot is performing systematically with success on switches directly connected to the core switch stack. On cascaded switches, ie switches connected to another switch but not to the core switch stack, pxe-boot is randomly performed: sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't. If I temporarily connect a cascaded switch to the core switch stack, pxe-boot from this switch becomes systematically successfull (and randomly performed on the previously attached-to-the-core-switch-stack one).
Both client computers and servers are on the same default VLAN #1. I have a DHCP server together with a dedicated WDS server that delivers ISO images.
I have made a synthetic view of the situation giving switches' interfaces configuration (see network-schema). I can add additional informations if necessary.
Thanks in advance for your help and technical tips on that subject.
Thomas
--
EDIT: additional informations asked for in the comments.
When failing, the client computer remains stuck on Start PXE over ipv4 message. The DHCP server shows no sign of the computer. So it seems like no DHCP address is allocated to the client.
Switch ports facing client computers are all configured as follow:
interface <if>
 tagged vlan 12
 untagged vlan 1
 spanning-tree admin-edge-port
 spanning-tree loop-guard bpdu-protection
 loop-protect
 exit


On which stage it fails (i.e. DHCP, TFTP)? How does the failure look from the client (on-screen error messages) and from the server (log records) standpoint? Did you try to perform a traffic capture to find out what's really happening?

It looks like DHCPDISCOVER packets even don't reach the server. This may be a sign of wrong port security configuration on the switch port you are cascading to. I'd start investigation there.

Thanks @NikitaKipriyanov. It's the randomness of the behaviour that raises questions. Why a port security configuration issue if pxe-boot sometimes performs successfully?

I don't know. For instance, one can permit a certain number of MAC addresses to appear on a port; this may only extend to DHCP. Do you have any deeper insights, like "fails if some other machine from the same switch successfully booted recently, and it's fixed if I reconnect the cascaded switch or otherwise reset port it is cascaded to", and so on? Anyway, the most suspicious place is the switch in the middle. Examine it's configuration closely (maybe, post it here), set up extended logging, capture traffic (maybe configure a port mirror).

In the past I remember there was limitation of how many switches you can cascade. Maybe this is the reason...

Please check your STP settings for ports facing client PCs and monitor STP port states during PXE initialization. It is a common issue for PXE stacks to cycle Ethernet adapter port link state to down and then up; this triggers STP to go through disabled/listening/learning phases on the port, during these events link looks to PXE as up, while in fact it does not forward any data. As a rule you should have ports facing PXE bootable PCs configured as Edge Ports with BPDU Guard enabled.

@PeterZhabin: I have updated the original post. Have you had a look at the schema on which I mentionned the used ports configurations? The options you mention are already there I assume. Is this what you meant?

Ok, I see. I'd suggest to set up a port mirroring session on the uplinks of the edge switch and intermediate switch to see what's really going on, at least you would know where DHCPDISCOVER is getting lost.

If there was a long time switch training a port connected to a PC it wouldn't work reliably even in a not cascaded configuration. I'd rather see the configuration on the cascaded uplink port and its vis-a-vis, on the downstream port of the middle switch where the edge is cascaded.

@RomeoNinov The design limit for STP network diameter is 7 - we're not close here.
